# Adding fade-out effect to last column in large table

Tags: html, css

For text that does not fit in side a cell it is possible to add ellipsis or a fade out effect using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` or`text-overflow: fade(10px);`. However this does not work if the table can overflow horizontally.

Is it possible to add a fadeout effect to the text or the table if a column or several columns do not fit within a table on screen? (In my scenario the horizontal scrollbar may not be visible when the table has many rows so this cue may not be shown to user.)

A right-most column would have a fade out to make it obvious that there are columns outside view-able area.

(I am using bootstrap 3.3.)

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kashiraja/ukov4646/)

Reference: [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: From what I can tell `text-overflow: fade` isn't supported by any of the major browsers. Do you have a specific use case where you're accounting for this? (experimental browser flags)

Comment: I should have been more clear, I'm not using text-overflow since it doesn't work for the scenario here. I want each visible column to be wide enough to show all content all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine wrapping the table in another div, you can use that div's after pseudo-element to have a gradient background.  See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y97j53s2/7/) (based off your provided fiddle) for an example of this.

The relevant style changes made in that fiddle are:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" style="margin-bottom: 0; overflow-x: visible;">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
<style>
  container{
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
  }

  .container::after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:200px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
  }

  .table{
    max-width:100%;
  }
</style>
```

Note that the container has a set width.  This means the table will overflow it.  The after-element needs to have content set, but we don't actually want any content visible so we use `''`.  After that it's just a matter of positioning it (using absolute so we can base it off the container div's position) and then giving it a background gradient.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was trying to do. Only thing is that the gradient moves with the table when horizontally scrolling. Is that what you are referring to, 'It's just a matter of positioning it'?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a different approach here if all you're interested in is signaling to the user that there's more data in the table than what is visible in the viewport.

My suggestion is to wrap the table inside a container `div` and limit the container size to the viewport size using [`vh` and `vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units) units. This way you're going to see a scrollbar whenever the table overflows vertically or horizontally.

```
.table-wrapper {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You can see an example of this here https://jsfiddle.net/ukov4646/5/

Comment: This is a good approach and simple, works well on desktop. On mobile (at least Chrome for Android) the horizontal scroll bar is hidden or vanishes after the user stops panning horizontally so the table is partially visible and the user may not realize that content in a column is hidden. The motivation is to avoid the last digit(s) in a column being hidden due to overflow -- or at least making the user aware of it.